# Is it possible to get the text of an invisible GridViewRow in the codebehind?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a GridView BoundField defined like this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Id" />
```

In the codebehind, I can get the instance of a row and read the text like this:

```
Row.Cells(0).Text
```

However, when I make the BoundField invisible like this...

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Id" Visible="false" />
```

...`Row.Cells(0).Text` returns an empty string.

The only solution I've found is to create an item and edit item template, put a hidden field in both, and then get the hidden field using `.FindControl()`.  I don't really like that idea, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `DataKeyNames` property of  gridview.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="MyGridView" DataKeyNames="Id">
</asp:GridView>
```

And access this ID value as:

```
var data = MyGridView.DataKeys[RowIndex].Values[KeyIndex]
```

so, in your case it can be as below for say 2nd row

```
var data = MyGridView.DataKeys[1].Values[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

So What you want is to access the field value from code behind that is being bound to the 
gridview.

You can simply define the row databound event of the gridview and access it simply like this

```
     protected void gvMyGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {

        int seminarId = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "PK_ID"));
    }

    //PK_ID is the database column name
}
```

In the aspx page you should have something like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMyGridView" runat="server" 
   AllowPaging="false" 
OnRowDataBound="gvSeminarRequestBucket_RowDataBound">
   <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="PK_ID" />
 </asp:GridView>
```

In case you feel some problem please feel free to ask

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add the `BoundField` to the aspx page and make it invisible. You can use DataBinder for this. If your need to access the `Id` value in the `ItemDataBound` event use this

```
private void OnItemDataBound(object sender, 
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        //Use DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ID") to receive Id value
    }
}
```